# How to get rid of `Google Map direction service's` markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

The Google map `Direction Service` Api has two **"side effects"**,

1- it adds `Markers` automatically to origin and destination.

2- it adds two `InfoWindow` to the new `Markers`, containing their addresses.

[image]

Any idea how to get rid of theese Markers and their infoBubble?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide marker from directions service in google maps api v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509917/hide-marker-from-directions-service-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add suppressMarkers: true to the [DirectionsRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)

```
suppressMarkers | boolean |Suppress the rendering of markers.
```